# Java: if statments and indents

Tags: java, if-statement

So question about Java indents and if statements. I'm familiar with python where the info may not transfer 1 to 1.

So if I had a for loop with an if statement in it, and I close that if statement with a } but the next line has the same indention place as the if statement. What happens in the the new line, after the if statement is closed. For example.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   if (i == 5) {
       do something here;
   }

       what happens here, is this the else that's not written explicitly?
}
```

Comment: In Java blank lines and indentation don't do anything; it just adds readability. If you wanted you could have everything on one line.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer. I'm used to python where the "what happens here' line would have thrown a indent error. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line you are referring to will be executed 10 times, regardless whether the `if` statement is true or false, i.e., is executed or not.

Indention in Java is just a way to make code more readable.

So the output would be (replacing "do something here;" with `System.out.println("i is 5")` and replacing "what happens here ..." with `System.out.println("i is not 5")` (actual value of `i` in square brackets, not part of the output):

```
i is not 5 [0]
i is not 5 [1]
i is not 5 [2]
i is not 5 [3]
i is not 5 [4]
i is 5     [5]
i is not 5 [5]
i is not 5 [6]
i is not 5 [7]
i is not 5 [8]
i is not 5 [9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 if (i == 5) {
     do something here;
 }
  //if you write something here, it will be executed after the if statement
}
```

If you would write that into else{} it would just be executed, if the if statement isn't true...

So the line after the if statement will be executed, even, when the if statement is true